# Inherit JS file and override a function in odoo 8

Tags: javascript, inheritance, odoo-8

I need to inherit below JS file and override the function `show_annoucement_bar` in it.

The base code is:

```
 openerp_announcement = function(instance) {
    instance.web.WebClient.include({
        show_application: function() {
            return $.when(this._super.apply(this, arguments)).then(this.proxy('show_annoucement_bar'));
        },
    _ab_location: function(dbuuid) {
        return _.str.sprintf('https://services.openerp.com/openerp-enterprise/ab/css/%s.css', dbuuid);
    },
    show_annoucement_bar: function() {
        //Base codes..............
    }
   });
};
```

I tried this:

```
 openerp_announcement.include({
 show_annoucement_bar: function() {
     alert('New function');
  }
)};
```

The new js file showing in html headr section. but not working?